# boost::hash/std::tr1::hash not returning same hash for copied const char*

Tags: c++, boost, hash

I have following code:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *str1 = "teststring";

    // copy string
    size_t len = strlen(str1);
    char *str2 = new char[len+1];
    strcpy(str2, str1);

    // hash strings
    std::cout << "str1: " << str1 << "; " << boost::hash<const char*>()(str1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "str2: " << str2 << "; " << boost::hash<const char*>()(str2) << std::endl;

    delete[] str2;

    return 0;
}
```

I always get the same hash for str1 (as expected). But str2 differs - in fact it returns a different hash every time I run the programm.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Thank you for including a full example.  That's pretty rare.

Comment: Could it be hashing the pointer, not the contents of the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Linuxios suggested, it's hashing the pointer value, not the string.  I did a quick test with this code:

```
char str1[] = "teststring";
std::cout << "str1: " << str1 << "; " << boost::hash<const char*>()(str1) << std::endl;
str1[3] = 'x';
std::cout << "str1: " << str1 << "; " << boost::hash<const char*>()(str1) << std::endl;
```

And here's the output.  Note that the string is different but since the pointer is the same the hash matches.

```
str1: teststring; 158326806782903
str1: tesxstring; 158326806782903
```

The only change you need to make is to tell boost it's hashing a `std::string` and it will give you matching hashes.  Your underlying data can remain `char*`.

```
std::cout << "str1: " << str1 << "; " << boost::hash<std::string>()(str1) << std::endl;
std::cout << "str2: " << str2 << "; " << boost::hash<std::string>()(str2) << std::endl;
```

Result:

```
str1: teststring; 10813257313199645213
str2: teststring; 10813257313199645213
```

Comment: It's working!. But is it hashing the pointers of *both* strings? The first is returning the same hash all the time. Or is it because it's a string literal?

Comment: @snøreven The address of the first string is fixed for each time you run the program--it's in the executable itself.  So, its hash will always be the same.  The other string comes from `malloc()` and will have a different address each time based on the state of the rest of your system.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want the hash of the string not the pointer then you can either use the `boost::hash_range` function or a custom loop using hash_combine and write your own hash function object.  `boost::hash<std::basic_string<...> >` does hashes using `hash_range`, with `has_range` in turn using `hash_combine`.

e.g. something like this:

```
struct CStringHash : public std::unary_function<char const*, std::size_t> {
    std::size_t operator()(char const* v) const {
        std::size_t seed = 0;
        for (; *v; ++v) {
            boost::hash_combine(seed, *v);
        }
        return seed;
    }
};
```